# JavaScript module.exports callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Folks,
  How do I get the results from Y back to the Z function?

code:

```
module.exports = {

    Z: function (req) {
        var x = req.body
        function getX (results) {
            console.log (results)
        }
        module.exports.Y(x, getX())
    },

    Y: function (x, upstreamCallback) {
        var locals = new Array();
        async.parallel([
            function a(callback) {
            },
            function b(callback) {
            },
        ], function (err) {
           console.log(locals)
           upstreamCallback(locals)
        })
    },
}
```

locals are being called properly, they are showing up in the console.  Problem is that locals are not being passed back to the Z...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a NodeJS person, but my highly educated guess is that you're intending to *pass* getX, not call it. If you remove the parentheses, it's passed in, and should then be called in Y as upstreamCallback.

Comment: I am a Node.js person, you're right. He's calling the getX function in-line, so it's just passing in the result of that function (`undefined`) as the callback, instead.